# Adding NOW() to a File uploader, file name

Tags: php, jquery-file-upload

Very simple one.. but im struggling with it. Im trying to add the time to my file name but i am getting nowhere just errors.

```
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
```

Any help will be great thanks

Update

```
 <?php


$targetFolder = '/legal/uploads'; 

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;

    //$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    $targetFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'].date("d-m-Y_H:i:s");  
    $fileTypes = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf', 'PDF'); 
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the time to the filename by

```
$targetFile = "FILE_".date("d-m-Y_H:i:s");
```

which will output the filename as FILE_28-02-2017_16:12:36
You can check out the desired [date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) from the documentation

Comment: Its understanding where to place it within the code im having issues with

Comment: what error do you get? According to your code, you can use above code like this `$targetFile =  $_FILES['Filedata']['name'].date("d-m-Y_H:i:s");`

Comment: I dont get any errors the file i am trying to upload does not save

Comment: but its acting as if its gone though fine

Comment: I have updated my full php file above, with your code added

Comment: In this case, you need to do this: `$targetFile = $targetPath.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'].date("d-m-Y_H:i:s");` Normally, this should work, unless you have more errors.

Comment: Also ensure that you are actually getting the file data by using `print_r($_FILES)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136886/discussion-between-alex-banerjee-and-niket-pathak).